# How to create a numeric localized (decimal separator) TextField?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to create a numeric TextField which will be localized.

For example, in Excel, if you are in english, if you type a number with the KeyPad, the decimal separator key will enter a dot '.'
But if you are in French, the decimal separator will be a comma ','

Therefore in Excel, the TextField is smart enough to detect in which Locale you're on, and to adapt the decimal separator you actually wanted to print in the TextField.

Right now in JavaFX, I haven't found a way to do that. I was thinking of listening to text modification and to replace any occurrence of dot with a comma if I detect I'm in French. But is this assumption true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend subclassing `TextField` and overriding the `insertText` and `replace*` methods. This will handle text entry before the text is updated; listening to text modifications and fixing them will mean you temporarily have "invalid" text in your text field's text property, which could create problems in the rest of your application.

Note that you can create a `java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols` object for the default (user) `Locale` (or a specified `Locale`, if you need), and call `getDecimalSeparator()` to find the correct decimal separator character. (Similarly, you can call `getGroupingSeparator()`.)

So, for proof of concept, this is nowhere near robust enough for production:

```
public class NumericTextField extends TextField {
    @Override
    public void insertText(int index, String text) {
        String fixedText = fixText(text);
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(getText().substring(0, index));
        newText.append(fixedText);
        if (index < getText().length()) {
            newText.append(getText().substring(index));
        }
        if (isValid(newText)) {
            super.insertText(index, fixedText);
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
        String fixedText = fixText(text);
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder(getText().substring(0, start));
        newText.append(fixedText);
        newText.append(getText().substring(end));
        if (isValid(newText)) {
            super.insertText(start, end, fixedText);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceText(IndexRange range, String text) {
        replaceText(range.getStart(), range.getEnd(), text);
    }


    private String fixText(String text) {
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
        return text.replaceAll("\\.", Character.toString(symbols.getDecimalSeparator()));
    }

    private boolean isValid(String text) {
        // check that the text is a valid numeric representation (or partial representation)
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are confirming that the hypothesis of replacing a dot with the decimal separator is valid?
Your solution seems very good. One last thing, with that solution, typing a dot will be impossible in French for example. It will always be replaced by a comma.
So there is no way to make the difference between a dot entered with the normal keyboard and a dot entered with the decimal separator key of the keypad?

Comment: Well, maybe. :). I don't have enough experience with international keyboards to be certain this works; for example, do keyboards configured for European locales still produce '.' from the decimal point on the number pad, or do they produce commas? Also, in some locales '.' is used as a grouping separator, so you may need to consider that too. The `KeyCode` enum has constants for the Number pad 0-9 keys, but no distinction seems to be made between a '.' on the number pad and on the regular keyboard. In short, I'm not offering anything definitive, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: Allright, if the KeyCode enum doesn't have a constant for the decimal separator on the keypad, then I don't see how we would do it. 
Anyway this solution is working really fine. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

In the events of a TextField, "setOnKeyPressed" and "setOnKeyReleased", the code of the key pressed can be obtained from the keyEvent and there it can be seen that the key code of the "." pressed from the main keyboard corresponds to the constant "PERIOD", while the keystroke code of "." pressed from the numeric keypad corresponds to the constant "DECIMAL".

From this concept, I share the closest thing I have achieved in this regard, where if I press the "." From the numeric keyboard, according to my specific need, I replace it with the character ",".

```
totalAmountText.setOnKeyReleased((keyEvent) -> {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == DECIMAL) {
            int pos = totalAmountText.getCaretPosition();
            totalAmountText.setText(totalAmountText.getText().replace(".", ","));
            totalAmountText.positionCaret(pos);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does not work with "setOnKeyPressed", since in this instance of the event, the typed character has not yet been dumped to the control, so the replacement function will not take effect.

Comment: this is completely wrong, using a textformatter (with a numberformat to decide about alloweable chars) is _the_ way to go

Answer (score -2):

I am attaching a new version of the code, which takes best practices from the code of the first answer:

```
    totalAmountText.setOnKeyReleased((keyEvent) -> {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == DECIMAL) {
            int pos = totalAmountText.getCaretPosition();
            DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
            totalAmountText.setText(totalAmountText.getText().replace(".", 
                Character.toString(symbols.getDecimalSeparator())));
            totalAmountText.positionCaret(pos);
        }
    });
```

Comment: don't duplicate your answer - instead edit the first (this is as wrong as the first, btw)